# Best way to convert org.threeten.bp.* and org.joda.time* to corresponding java.time.* class

Tags: java, java-8, jodatime, java-time, threetenbp

I am working on a project that uses a shared library which uses org.threeten for Date/Time. As the library is shared across many projects it cannot be upgraded to Java 8 yet (sigh). 
The shortest way seems to be toString()/parse() combination

```
java.time.OffsetDateTime.parse(org.threeten.bp.OffsetDateTime.toString())
java.time.LocalDate.parse(org.threeten.bp.LocalDate.toString())
```

But more efficient way in terms of garbage creation will probably be the use of [.of(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#of-int-int-int-int-int-int-int-java.time.ZoneOffset-) methods:

```
java.time.OffsetDateTime.of(tt.getYear(), tt.getMonth(), tt.getDayOfMonth(), ...)
```

Have you stumbled upon a library that provides all this sort of conversions between Joda, Threeten and java.time classes?

Comment: I would get the millis since the epoch and the offset id, then you only have two fields to pass rather than all of them.

Comment: @BoristheSpider you can do that as well. But as with the toString()/parse() methods it will have the overhead of calculating each field back from the instant since epoch. Java 8 time classes internally store all the fields separately (point 4 http://blog.joda.org/2009/11/why-jsr-310-isn-joda-time_4941.html).

Answer (score 2):

The neatest way would be to fork ThreeTen-Backport and make the termporal interfaces extend their Java 8 counterparts. That way, you could do `OffsetDateTime.from(threeTenOffsetDateTime)` and so on.

I'm not aware of any existing fork that does this.